# class within an div using php echo

Tags: php, if-statement, echo, request-uri

Just basically want to know if its possible adding an `class` to my `div` which i `echo` using an if statement.

My code:

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($currentpage == "/room/penthouse-suite/"){
echo "<div class="' .text-center text-emphasis text-lg. '">test 
penthouse</div>";
}
elseif ($currentpage == "/room/garden-room/"){
echo "<div class="text-center text-emphasis text-lg">test garden</div>";
}
elseif ($currentpage == "/room/ocean-suite/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test ocean</div>";
}
elseif ($currentpage == "/room/mountain-suite/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test mountain</div>";
}
```

As you can see i did try a couple of ways, but not getting it working.

Comment: The last two look valid, the first and second one has syntax errors

Comment: your 3rd & 4th conditions should work. I hope, since the errors are in the first 2 conditions, it is not getting you to go through

Comment: first and second have quotes problem, third and fourth looking good

Comment: yess thanks, took out all of them and tested one at a time and realised that using ' ' would work, thanks guys. rookie error

Comment: second question if you would like to help, for the output e.g. test garden , i want this to display in parentheses , how would i go about achieving that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Basically just used single quotes in side the double quotes.(easy)

```
if ($currentpage == "/room/penthouse-suite/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test 
penthouse</div>";
}
elseif ($currentpage == "/room/garden-room/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test garden</div>";
}
elseif ($currentpage == "/room/ocean-suite/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test ocean</div>";
}
elseif ($currentpage == "/room/mountain-suite/"){
echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test mountain</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

double-quotes should not be used inside double-quotes and single-quotes should not be used inside single-quotes. I resolved this replacing quotes. Please try this

```
if ($currentpage == "/room/penthouse-suite/") {
            echo '<div class="text-center text-emphasis text-lg">test 
penthouse</div>';
        } elseif ($currentpage == "/room/garden-room/") {
            echo '<div class="text-center text-emphasis text-lg">test garden</div>';
        } elseif ($currentpage == "/room/ocean-suite/") {
            echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test ocean</div>";
        } elseif ($currentpage == "/room/mountain-suite/") {
            echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test mountain</div>";
        }
```

Comment: second question if you would like to help, for the output e.g. test garden , i want this to display in parentheses , how would i go about achieving that?

Comment: `echo "<div class='text-center text-emphasis text-lg'>test garden</div>";` this works perfectly, but how do i output test garden on my page in parentheses ?

Comment: I think you want like (test garden)  ?

Comment: "test garden"   --->  how the output should be displayed on my page.

Comment: for test garden if you simply put " you can get in output because it is inside  single-quotes. even if not getting then use \" .

Comment: You can use double quotes in a double quoted string, but you need to escape it if so. Same applies to single quotes